# Does authentication differ at all when creating an app with angular?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

In a regular web app, when someone logs into the system they simply save an encrypted cookie that gets send on each request and the backend decrypts the cookie and uses the e.g. user_id/guid to lookup the user.

How do things differ when authenticating with a angular app?
Is there anything else to consider or it is basically the same process?

Answer (score 0):

We use more or less the same mechanism.

- Access to the application as a whole requires authentication - that is unless you're logged in, you don't get any of the javascript experience at all.  This could make the login / login failure much less wizzy for the user, but in our authentication provider it's fine.
- Part of our auth mechanism means the list of roles that the user has is a data object available within the browser.  The javascript code uses this to decide which buttons / menus etc. are displayed.  I checked with our security guy and he said something like "Well, it's a kind of direct object reference issue, but as long as each action is authorised properly, you're probably ok."  So it's possible that a user could hack data values and change what they can see, but because of the next bit, they can't break our data (or see stuff that they shouldn't).
- Each service call our javascript makes is authenticated and authorised. That is, the javascript call will fail if the auth token is missing or bad, but also, we internally match the auth token with a user and a set of permissions, and only execute that if the user is authorised to do so.  (Note that this is good practice whether you're using Angular or not).  Also note that this applies to GETs as well as POSTs - we don't want to *give* them data they should not see.

It gets much trickier if your API is hosted separately from your Angular site.